# Unable to launch web app on IIS Server and client

Tags: c#, selenium

I cloned [this web app](https://github.com/executeautomation/ExecuteAutomationWebApp.git) from `ExecuteAutoEmployee` in GitHub, but I can't launch it both from the client and from the IIS server then deployed. I am having the following issues:

> The system cannot find the file specified Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 18:  Line 19:             var migrator = new DbMigrator(new
>   Configuration()); Line 20:             migrator.Update(); Line 21:
>   Line 22:
>
> Source File:
>   D:\Repositories\ExecuteAutomationWebApp\ExecuteAutoEmployee\Global.asax.cs
>   Line: 20
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +345
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +156
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +258
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +312
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +202
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +413    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +128
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +503
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
>   +560    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +18
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +234
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +927
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String
>   createDatabaseScript) +124
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +221
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
>   connection) +125
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +156
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration) +116
>   ExecuteAutoEmployee.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   D:\Repositories\ExecuteAutomationWebApp\ExecuteAutoEmployee\Global.asax.cs:20
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +520
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +176
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +165
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +353
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +341
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +107    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +688
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0

```
using ExecuteAutoEmployee.Migrations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ExecuteAutoEmployee
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {    
            var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
            migrator.Update();               

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What SQL Server is it trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your connection string to your db is incorrect, or the SQL server it's connecting to is on another server that isn't setup to accept remote connections.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I commented out this bit of code and it worked

```
 var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
        migrator.Update();
```